# Export current rendered view/template as a PDF with Nativescript-VueJS

Tags: javascript, nativescript, html2pdf, nativescript-vue

Using NativeScript + VueJS, I'm trying to find a way to take a dynamic template that's rendered based on props and route data, and tap a button to save the "view" as a PDF to the filesystem.

I found this tutorial here which gives me a start: https://medium.com/@kumarandena/pdf-generation-in-nativescript-using-javascript-libraries-864ecf4e9a3a

This generates a Base64 which you then copy to clipboard and open in a browser. In iOS for example if I choose to save the page as a file it's just `unknown.pdf`. So my goal is to reference an html element, like a div, and save all the contents exactly as they appear into a folder of my choice in the native file system.

There's little to find on this so wondering if someone has accomplished this.

Comment: Your UI is not HTML Dom nor running within a WebView so you can not export it as a PDF, may be you could save it as an image and embed the image in your PDF.

Comment: I have it saving so far as basic PDF, but not html content. I was hoping to be able to use `HtmlView` in nativescript to generate the content. That's where I'm at this very moment.

Comment: If you goal is to convert HTML source from HtmlView / WebView into PDF, you may try [nativescript-html2pdf](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-html2pdf) plugin.

Comment: @Manoj I did look at that but currently only Android is supported it states. I'm using JsPdf and I'll know shortly if it'll correctly save it. However I'm going to assume I'll run into issues with styling.

Answer (score 0):

I use [domtoimage](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image)  to convert any dom element to an image, and it works well. Then you can probably insert that image to a pdf using jsPDF or pdfMake.

I see in the [pdfMake playground](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html) that you can insert an image with a dataurl format.